# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with Swift

Tags: swift

I'm playing with Swift and I have a weird problem running my project.

I have two classes: **homeViewController** and **Photo**.

This is the main code:

**homeViewController:**

```
class homeViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
// .... some code...
func publishPhoto(){

        var photo = Photo()

        // Establecemos el loading
        photoDesc.resignFirstResponder()
        let loading = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
        loading.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate
        loading.labelText = "Un segundo por favor...";

        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoInfo["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as UIImage, 100.0)

        photo.addPhoto()

        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)

    }
// .... some code ....
}
```

**Photo**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Photo: UIViewController{

    func addPhoto(){

        var homeCtrl = homeViewController()

        homeCtrl.photoDesc.resignFirstResponder()

        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(homeCtrl.photoInfo["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as UIImage, 100.0)

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
        var parameters = ["user":"admin","password":"123456", "image" : imageData]
        manager.POST( "http://misdemos.dev/simpleApi/prueba",
            parameters: parameters,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            })

    }

}
```

I'm getting the error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` in this line:

> manager.requestSerializer.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4",
>   forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")

If I put the addPhoto() code directly in homeViewController.publishPhoto it works...

This is my first time with iOS and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As an aside: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION is almost always issued by an assertion failure in the standard library. Assertion failures deliberately issue a bad CPU instruction to halt the program. You often see them caused by an object being nil because it's not been set up properly.

Comment: Might try running under Beta 3, there is now a console message for some of the cases that cause this. In my case, a cocoa method was returning an implicitly unwrapped optional (return type of Type!) which you don't have to check, but still might be nil.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create requestSerializer and responseSerializer before setting header field.

For example JSON serializer:

```
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
```

Another option is to create request like this:

```
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: "http://misdemos.dev/simpleApi/prueba")
request.setValue("608c6c08443c6d933576b90966b727358d0066b4", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")    
let operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)     

// e.g. response is json
operation.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess(...)

operation.start()
```